# angular-cli how to add sass and or bootstrap?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying out angular-cli and trying to get sass and bootstrap in the project. I've read in the [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Stories) that you can simply do:

```
ng install sass
```

Doing this with the current latest (beta.5) gives me an error:

```
Install failed. Could not find addon with name: sass
```

How can I go about installing bootstrap and or sass in a way that angular-cli will deal with the index page and systemJS?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> **NOTE**: This answer is out of date due to changes in the Angular CLI, please refer to the answer below from Woot which is more current.

You need to install `node-sass` via `npm i node-sass --save-dev` then change your styleExt in `angular-cli.json` to either `sass` or `scss` (or you can set that via `ng set defaults.styleExt scss`

As for bootstrap, place it under the `public` directory (I use a sub dir named `style`) and reference it within `index.html`

**UPDATE:**
Also if you'd like to have variables files you can add the directory to `angular-cli-build.js` like this...

```
return new Angular2App(defaults, {
  vendorNpmFiles: [
    ...
  ],
  sassCompiler: {
    includePaths: [
      'src/app/style' <-- directory for SASS reference files
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: I was under the impression ng install <lib> handled it all. Thank-you for the clarification.

Comment: No problem, also updated with how to add reference files.

Comment: ng install is no longer supported (Feb 2017)

Comment: @gotofritz it has not been supported for a LONG time

Answer (score 65):

If you create your project with the angular-cli it comes with a scss preprocessor.  If you have styles files you can just change the ext to scss and ng serve will compile them for you.

When you create a project using the cli you can tell it that you want to use scss by

```
ng new sassy-project --style=sass
```

If you have an existing project Angular 2 to 5

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

If your project is Angular 6 and 7

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext sass
```

These tell the cli that when you generate new components with scss styles not css.  It doesn't add a compiler or enable the compiler because there is already one there.

Any existing components would need their style file extensions renamed.

Additional documentation https://angular.io/cli

Hope this helps

Comment: The readme linked to above describes installing Bootstrap which I found helpful. Where the readme talks about installing Bootstrap, it references "app[0].scripts" and "app[0].styles". It wasn't clear to me what that meant, but updating the angular-cli.json file in the 'scripts' and 'sytles' section seems to work. This answer says pretty much the same thing: [how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project?rq=1). Look for answer by Nelly Sattari. Thanks for pointing me to the readme.

Comment: or `ng new sassy-project --style=scss` if you prefer `scss` more than `sass`

Comment: do you know where the generated css is saved ?

Comment: `get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command.`

Answer (score 6):

Change these lines of `angular-cli.json` from

```
"apps": [
    {
        "styles": [
                "styles.css"
              ]
    }
]
```

to

```
"apps": [
    {
        "styles": [
                "styles.sass"
              ]
    }
]
```

after setting styleExt

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

Then change `src/style.css` to `src/style.sass` and `['app.component.css']` to `['app.component.sass']`. It will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After Creating with

```
ng create "project"
```

go to the project directory and try with

```
npm install sass
```

it will update your package.json

Comment: Just using `npm install sass` will just install the package into the node_modules directory but not update the package.json file. To save it to package.json, you need to use `-D` or `-save-dev` flags to save it as a dev dependency, or even `-S` or `-save` to save it as a runtime dependency. Otherwise, that package will not be installed for any new clones and is at risk of being purged via `npm purge`.

Comment: Yes, it should be "npm install sass" instead of "ng install sass".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Woot for his answer, this answer is more for .NET Core 2.0/2.1 developers using the angular seed project via:

```
#get lastest SPA templates and make sure angular CLI is global
dotnet new --install Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::*
npm install -g @angular/cli

#create a new project, default for target framework doesn't seem to be working when .NET Core 2.1 SDK is Installed
dotnet new angular -f netcoreapp2.0 -o test-web-app
```

This seed project still uses a bootstrap 3 version so it requires the download of bootstrap-sass (or an upgrade to bootstrap 4 which includes scss support in the base node module):

```
npm install bootstrap-sass --save-dev
```

In the .angular-cli.json file change the styles configuration from this:

```
"styles": [
   "styles.css",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
]
```

to:

```
"styles": [
   "styles.scss",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss"
]
```

And as Woot pointed out, the upgrade of the angular cli configuration to create scss files instead of css files when autocreating file should also be performed by:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

And renaming you **styles.css** file to **styles.scss** is required.

The angular CLI and angular version are also slightly out of date as of this writing (1.7.0 and 5.2.0), so this answer is subject to change once those are upgraded. *But as of right now,* this works and nothing else needs to be done to allow:

```
dotnet run
```

to support the automatic compilation of scss to css and serving the files under the hood via **ng serve**.