# How to add bootstrap to an angular-cli project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-cli, ngx-bootstrap

We want to use bootstrap 4 (4.0.0-alpha.2) in our app generated with angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.5 (w/ node v6.1.0).

After getting bootstrap and its dependencies with npm, our first approach consisted in adding them in `angular-cli-build.js`:

```
'bootstrap/dist/**/*.min.+(js|css)',  
'jquery/dist/jquery.min.+(js|map)',  
'tether/dist/**/*.min.+(js|css)',
```

and import them in our `index.html`

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This worked fine with `ng serve` but as soon as we produced a build with `-prod` flag all these dependencies disappeared from `dist/vendor` (surprise !).

**How we are intended to handle such scenario (i.e. loading bootstrap scripts) in a project generated with angular-cli ?**

We had the following thoughts but we don't really know which way to go...

- use a CDN ? but we would rather serve these files to guarantee that they will be available
- copy dependencies to `dist/vendor` after our `ng build -prod` ? But that seems like something angular-cli should provide since it 'takes care' of the build part ?
- adding jquery, bootstrap and tether in `src/system-config.ts` and somehow pull them into our bundle in `main.ts` ? But that seemed wrong considering that we are not going to explicitly use them in our application's code (unlike moment.js or something like lodash, for example).

Comment: Do you have them in your system-config.ts file? you have to map them.

Comment: Many of the answers below recommend the use of ngx-bootstrap. I found that it is not a full replacement for Bootstrap's jquery plugins and sometimes you still need to use those "native" jquery plugins, such as collapse functionality in tables. In that case look for one of the answers below that explain how to explicitly import the jquery script from the .angular-cli.json file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557321/angular-4-how-to-include-bootstrap

Comment: Just use ng-bootstrap https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Answer (score 341, accepted):

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** *ng2-bootstrap* is now replaced by [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)

*ngx-bootstrap* supports both Angular 3 and 4.

**Update :** 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack or above versions

First of all check your **angular-cli** version with the following command in the terminal:

```
ng -v
```

If your **angular-cli** version is greater than *1.0.0-beta.11-webpack*, then you should follow these steps:

1. Install *ngx-bootstrap* and *bootstrap*:

   ```
   npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap --save
   ```

This line installs Bootstrap 3 nowadays, but can install Bootstrap 4 in the future. Keep in mind *ngx-bootstrap* supports both versions.

2. Open **src/app/app.module.ts** and add:

   ```
   import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
   ...
   @NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [AlertModule.forRoot(), ... ],
   ... 
   })
   ```
3. Open **angular-cli.json** (for angular6 and later file name changed to **angular.json** ) and insert a new entry into the `styles` array:

   ```
   "styles": [
   "styles.css",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   ],
   ```
4. Open **src/app/app.component.html** and add:

   ```
   <alert type="success">hello</alert>
   ```

**1.0.0-beta.10 or below versions:**

And, if your **angular-cli** version is *1.0.0-beta.10* or below, then you can use below steps.

First, go to the project directory and type:

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

Then, open your **angular-cli-build.js** and add this line:

```
vendorNpmFiles: [
   ...
   'ngx-bootstrap/**/*.js',
   ...
]
```

Now, open your **src/system-config.ts** then write:

```
const map:any = {
   ...
   'ngx-bootstrap': 'vendor/ngx-bootstrap',
   ...
}
```

...and:

```
const packages: any = {
  'ngx-bootstrap': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'ngx-bootstrap.js'
  }
};
```

Comment: What is ng2-bootstrap exactly. what does adding native bootstrap to angular 2 mean? Sorry I am confused and have looked it up but am still confused. why can't I take these same steps to download bootstrap instead of using a 3rd party ng2-bootstrap.

Comment: @mjwrazor it's because bootstrap is not just about styles. it's a front-end framework. to be clear check out using [rating component](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/rating) with ng2-bootstrap and think about the codes you would write to implement it.

Comment: Great answer, thanks alot! How can I use scss/sass in this way?

Comment: I never used scss/sass but i think , that would not be that complicated. Btw, if you think it is a good answer dont mind to upvote it :D

Comment: https://github.com/ngCli/ng-cli/issues/18 any help with this issue i glad to get it

Comment: Just a small notice for future readers: Angular CLI has switched from SystemJS to WebPack with beta.14. This answer is now outdated, since it provides a solution based on SystemJS.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using ng2-bootstrap, here I found a installation manual for angular cli, on github page. https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md In my case there was missing the AlertModule.forRoot() call on imports.

Comment: I had the same issue with `angular-cli@1.1.3` & `ngx-bootstrap@1.7.1`. Following this steps with the difference at `app.module.ts` not referring to **ngx-bootstrap** by 'ngx-bootstrap/ngx-bootstrap' but by 'ngx-bootstrap' as on this example at [github](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md) fix my problem.

Comment: Note that `angular-cli.json` is now hidden, so you need `.angular-cli.json`. I suspect that means there's a better way to do this??

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Unfortunately I can't load bootstrap panels with this. But the alert example you mentioned works. Can you help with that, please?

Comment: Finally good solution. Could not find angular-cli.json (angular-cli 6.1.1) so i have changed angular.json file, "styles" section. I've added "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: Worked for me, though I needed `"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` instead of `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`!

Comment: Just as an addition, to check version in Angular v12, you just use ng v

Comment: My `angular.json` doesn't have a `styles` array. Can I add one? Where?

Answer (score 195):

Looking up for the keyword > Global Library Installation
on https://github.com/angular/angular-cli helps you find the answer.

As per their document, you can take the following steps to add the Bootstrap library.

First, install Bootstrap from npm:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Then add the needed script file to apps[0].scripts in the angular.json file:

```
 "scripts": [
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    ],
```

The above step is important for certain functionality to work such as the displaying of the dropdown menu.

Finally add the Bootstrap CSS file to the apps[0].styles array in the angular.json file:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
```

**Restart ng serve if you're running it, otherwise the changes will not be visible. Bootstrap 4+ should now be working on your app.**

**Alternative solution:**
Another solution to add Bootstrap to Angular would be to make use of the ngx-bootstrap project which provides Bootstrap components powered by Angular. Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37674735/4989481) to learn more regarding the use of ngx-boostrap with Angular or the ngx-bootstrap project's own [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation).

Comment: As I type, this is the only solution that seems to use the latest version of angular-cli.

Comment: The bootstrap.js is surely NOT needed! As you do not want to use the juqery bootstrap.js for this you must install the ng2 directives of bootstrap.

Comment: If you did want to use the bootstrap javascript as opposed to just the .css you would also need to include its dependencies in the scripts array: "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
"../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js", "../node/modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"

Comment: You better use bootstrap.bundle.js in your scripts declaration which also has popper.js.

Comment: To make work don't miss the **last point** execute `ng serve` again. Also why can't Angular CLI add this automatically ? It would be good if we have an option for it.

Comment: Adding minified version would be appropriate  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: You need to also include jQuery lib before the bootstrap.js import.

Answer (score 76):

Do the following:

```
npm i bootstrap@next --save
```

This will add bootstrap 4 to your project.

Next go to your `src/style.scss` or `src/style.css` file (choose whichever you are using) and import bootstrap there:

For style.css

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

For style.scss

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

For scripts you will still have to add the file in the angular-cli.json  file like so (*In Angular version 6, this edit needs to be done in the file **angular.json**)*:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```

Comment: IMHO this is also a great option, especially with the latest versions of angular-cli. The great advantage is that this method does not depend on people updating the library from npm package mentioned in the accepted answer; furthermore, this also enables us to possibly override bootstrap variables using SASS while not directly pointing to compiled CSS files.

Comment: Yep, it is cleaner and more modular, thus I prefer it!

Comment: This doent works for me, any prerequisites to follow, i am using latest version of angular and bootstrap and added all the above changes, didnt worked this way but worked on adding <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> in index.html

Comment: This is using the cli setup!

Comment: Only this one worked for me, I think this process should be more straightforward using the Angular-cli

Comment: for style.scss I had to add this : @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

Comment: a cleaner method would be     @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap';  Using the ~ sign to import like a module directly from node_modules folder. Found an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535760/what-does-a-tilde-in-a-css-url-do

Comment: What if want to use bootstrap 3 ?

Comment: Best for latest versions of angular

Comment: Note that `@import '~bootstrap'` is enough. Webpack will find `node_modules/bootstrap/project.json` which contains an entry `"style": "dist/css/bootstrap.css"`, which Webpack will use. Also note that this CSS file is not minified, which is good, since the CSS file will go through the same pipeline as the rest of application CSS files, which will get minified for production, and a proper source map will be produced as well.

Answer (score 33):

At first, you have to install tether, jquery and bootstrap with these commands

```
npm i -S tether
npm i -S jquery
npm i -S bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.4
```

After add these lines in your angular-cli.json (angular.json from version 6 onwards) file

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-flex.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ]
```

Comment: did you mean $projectRoot/.angular-cli.json?

Answer (score 26):

Since nobody referred to the official (angular-cli team) story on how to include Bootstrap yet: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap

## Include [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a popular CSS framework which can be used within an Angular project.
This guide will walk you through adding bootstrap to your Angular CLI project and configuring it to use bootstrap.

### Using CSS

#### Getting Started

Create a new project and navigate into the project

```
ng new my-app
cd my-app
```

#### Installing Bootstrap

With the new project created and ready you will next need to install bootstrap to your project as a dependency.
Using the `--save` option the dependency will be saved in package.json

```
# version 3.x
npm install bootstrap --save

# version 4.x
npm install bootstrap@next --save
```

#### Configuring Project

Now that the project is set up it must be configured to include the bootstrap CSS.

- Open the file `.angular-cli.json` from the root of your project.
- Under the property `apps` the first item in that array is the default application.
- There is a property `styles` which allows external global styles to be applied to your application.
- Specify the path to `bootstrap.min.css`

It should look like the following when you are done:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

**Note:** When you make changes to `.angular-cli.json` you will need to re-start `ng serve` to pick up configuration changes.

#### Testing Project

Open `app.component.html` and add the following markup:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Test Button</button>
```

With the application configured, run `ng serve` to run your application in develop mode.
In your browser navigate to the application `localhost:4200`.
Verify the bootstrap styled button appears.

### Using SASS

#### Getting Started

Create a new project and navigate into the project

```
ng new my-app --style=scss
cd my-app
```

#### Installing Bootstrap

```
# version 3.x
npm install bootstrap-sass --save

# version 4.x
npm install bootstrap@next --save
```

#### Configuring Project

Create an empty file `_variables.scss` in `src/`.

If you are using `bootstrap-sass`, add the following to `_variables.scss`:

```
$icon-font-path: '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/';
```

In `styles.scss` add the following:

```
// version 3
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap';

// version 4
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

#### Testing Project

Open `app.component.html` and add the following markup:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Test Button</button>
```

With the application configured, run `ng serve` to run your application in develop mode.
In your browser navigate to the application `localhost:4200`.
Verify the bootstrap styled button appears.
To ensure your variables are used open `_variables.scss` and add the following:

```
$brand-primary: red;
```

Return the browser to see the font color changed.

Comment: This solution does not add the javascript files for bootstrap, only the css

Comment: See this other story: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib. It describes adding script files, taking bootstrap 4 as an example.

Comment: `$brand-primary: red;` did not work for me. However, `$primary: red;`did!

Comment: Thanks for explaining difference between bootstrap vs boostrap@next :-)

Answer (score 18):

**Update v1.0.0-beta.26**

You can see on the doc for the new way for importing bootstrap [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md)

If it still does not work, restart with the command ng serve

**1.0.0 or below versions:**

In your index.html file you just need bootstrap css link (no need js scripts)

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And

```
npm install ng2-bootstrap --save
npm install moment --save
```

After having installed   [ng2-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) in **my_project/src/system-config.ts :**

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment.js',
  'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'ng2-bootstrap': {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'moment':{
     format: 'cjs'
  }
};
```

And in **my_project/angular-cli-build.js :**

```
module.exports = function (defaults) {
return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
        'ng2-bootstrap/**/*',
        'moment/moment.js'
    ]
});
};
```

**Don't forget this command 
to put your module in the vendor :**

```
ng build
```

to import from another module that is the same principle.

Comment: how does this make bootstrap able to use jquery? I have done this and this does not work.

Comment: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438683/is-there-a-way-to-build-the-mobile-nav-bar-in-ng2-bootsrap) finally found this and it worked. I could not figure this out for while.

Answer (score 11):

1. Install bootstrap

   ```
   npm install bootstrap@next
   ```
2. Add code to .angular-cli.json:

   ```
   "styles": [
     "styles.css",
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
   ],
   "scripts": [
     "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
     "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
   ],
   ```
3. Last add bootstrap.css to your code style.scss

   ```
   @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
   ```
4. Restart your local server

Comment: While ngx-bootstrap is nice for the components that it supports, sometimes you still need to use "native" jquery plugins, such as collapse functionality in tables. Then you still need to explicitly import the jquery script, which this answer shows.

Comment: Upvoted for point 4 (Restart your local server) I am using --->  npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap --save

Comment: The order of files matters.

Answer (score 9):

> **Steps for Bootstrap 4 in Angular 5**

1. Create Angular 5 Project

   **ng new AngularBootstrapTest**
2. Move to project directory

   **cd AngularBootstrapTest**
3. Download bootstrap

   **npm install bootstrap**
4. Add Bootstrap to Project

   4.1 open .angular-cli.json

   4.2 find the "styles" section in the json

   4.3 add the bootstrap css path as below

   .

   ```
   "styles": [
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "styles.css"
   ],
   ```

> Now you have succesfully added the bootstrap css in angular 5 project

**Test bootstrap**

5. open `src/app/app.component.html`
6. add bootstrap button component

.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

you can refer the button styles here( https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/ )

7. save the file
8. run the project

   **ng serve --open**

Now You will see the bootstrap style button in the page

Note : 
 if you added bootstrap path after **ng serve** , you must stop and rerun the ng serve to reflect the changes

Answer (score 9):

**2 simple steps**

---

1. Install Bootstrap ( am installing latest version)

---

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

2. Import into your project, add below line in your styles.scss

---

```
@import '~bootstrap';
```

---

Please Note your order of imports might matter, if you have other libraries which uses bootstrap, please keep this import statement on top

The End. :)

---

NOTE: below are my versions

---

angular : 9

node : v10.16.0

npm : 6.9.1

---

Answer (score 7):

I guess the above methods have changed after the release, check this link out

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md

**initiate project**

```
npm i -g angular-cli
ng new my-app
cd my-app
ng serve
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

**install ng-bootstrap and bootstrap**

```
npm install ng2-bootstrap bootstrap --save
```

**open src/app/app.module.ts and add**

```
import { AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
...

@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [AlertModule, ... ],
    ... 
})
```

**open angular-cli.json and insert a new entry into the styles array**

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
```

**open src/app/app.component.html and test all works by adding**

```
<alert type="success">hello</alert>
```

Comment: Method from Ahmed Hamdy works, apparently code update occured now. Updated his message with solution.

Comment: if you want to use Bootstrap 4 then you need to change "npm install ng2-bootstrap bootstrap --save" TO BE "npm install ng2-bootstrap bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --save" .... not entirely obvious in the documentation (do a search for 'card-' in bootstrap.css to know if it has worked) ... note that it is currently Alpha 6 this will change no doubt... check bootstrap site for current npm instruction

Answer (score 7):

**Run This Command**

```
npm install bootstrap@3
```

**your Angular.json**

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
```

Answer (score 7):

Install boostrap

`npm install --save bootstrap`

Then we need to import Bootstrap Sass into our application. In styles.scss add this line:

`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`

[For more info...](https://blog.shikisoft.com/how-to-import-bootstrap-4-sass-into-angular-4/)

Answer (score 6):

Since this became so confusing and the answers here are totally mixed I will just suggest going with the **official ui-team for BS4** repo (yes there are so many of those repos for NG-Bootstrap.

Just follow the instructions here https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap to get BS4.

Quoting from the lib:

> This library is being built from scratch by the ui-bootstrap team. We
>   are using TypeScript and targeting the Bootstrap 4 CSS framework.
>
> As with Bootstrap 4, this library is a work in progress. Please check
>   out our list of issues to see all the things we are implementing. Feel
>   free to make comments there.

Just copy pasting what is there for the sake of it:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Once installed you need to import our main module:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

The only remaining part is to list the imported module in your application module. The exact method will be slightly different for the root (top-level) module for which you should end up with the code similar to (notice NgbModule.forRoot()):

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Other modules in your application can simply import NgbModule:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [OtherComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule, ...], 
})
export class OtherModule {
}
```

This seems to be the most consistent behavior by far

Answer (score 5):

Do the following steps:

1. `npm install --save bootstrap`
2. And in your .angular-cli.json, add to styles section:

`"styles": [ "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "styles.css"]`

After that, you must restart your ng serve

Enjoy

Answer (score 5):

1. Install Bootstrap using npm

   ```
   npm install bootstrap
   ```

2.Install Popper.js

```
npm install --save popper.js
```

3.Goto **angular.json** in Angular 6 project / **.angular-cli.json** in Angular 5 and add the listed:

```
 "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],

        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal/command prompt in the respective project directory and type following command.

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

Then open .angular-cli.json file, Look for

`"styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],`

change that to

```
 "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

All done.

Answer (score 3):

Now with new **ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-beta.5** version supports most of the native Angular directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS.

The only dependency required to work with this is `bootstrap`. No Need to use **jquery** and **popper.js** dependencies.

ng-bootstrap is to completely replaced JavaScript implementation for components. So you don't need to include `bootstrap.min.js` in the scripts section in your .angular-cli.json.

follow these steps when you are integrating bootstrap with generated project with angular-cli latest version.

- Inculde `bootstrap.min.css` in your .angular-cli.json, styles section.

  ```
  "styles": [
     "styles.scss",
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  ```
- Install **ng-bootstrap** dependency.

  ```
  npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
  ```
- Add this to your main module class.

  ```
  import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
  ```
- Include the following in your main module imports section.

  ```
  @NgModule({
     imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
  })
  ```
- Do the following also in your sub module(s) if you are going to use ng-bootstrap components inside those module classes.

  ```
  import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

  @NgModule({
     imports: [NgbModule, ...],
  })
  ```
- Now your project is ready to use available ng-bootstrap components.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install bootstrap, popper.js

`npm install --save bootstrap`
`npm install --save popper.js`

3. In **src/styles.css**, import bootstrap's style

`@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Answer (score 3):

I see lot of the solutions don't work anymore with the new versions of Angular-CLI.

You can try to add the following link tag at top and script tags at the bottom in your app.component.html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But if you want to use ngx-bootstrap then run the following command in your project directory

```
ng add ngx-bootstrap
```

Test it out with following as the content of your app.component.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Light</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Dark</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

for bootstrap 4.5, angular 10

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

update your styles.scss like this with bootstrap import statement.

```
 $theme-colors: (
    "primary":    #b867c6,
    "secondary":  #f3e5f5,
    "success":    #388e3c,
    "info":       #00acc1,
    "light":      #f3e5f5,
    "dark":       #863895
);

@import "~bootstrap";

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap');

body {
    color: gray('800');
    background-color: theme-color('light');
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

importing bootstrap should be after your variable overwrites. [this example also shows how you can put your own theme colors.]

Answer (score 2):

You can also watch this video by Mike Brocchi which has useful information on how to add bootstrap to your Angular-Cli generated project. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obbdFFbjLIU (around minutes 13:00)

Answer (score 2):

1. Run in bash `npm install ng2-bootstrap bootstrap --save`
2. Add/Change the following in `angular-cli.json`
   `"styles": [
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     ],
     "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
       ],`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation

Answer (score 2):

Run this following command inside the project

```
npm install --save @bootsrap@4
```

and if you get a confirmation like this

```
+ bootstrap@4.1.3
updated 1 package in 8.245s
```

It means boostrap 4 is successfully installed. However, in order to use it, you need to update the "styles" array under the angular.json file.

Update it the following way so that bootstrap will be able to override the existing styles

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
           "src/styles.css"
          ],
```

To make sure everything is set up correctly, run `ng serve > open browser at http://localhost:4200/ or a port you run the angular app > right click > inspect > under the head check the styles if you have bootsrap like shown below`, then you are good to use boostrap.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Step1:
    `npm install bootstrap@latest --save-dev`
This will install the latest version of the bootstrap, 
However, the specified version can be installed by adding the version number

Step2: Open styles.css and add the following
    `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"`

Comment: Mostly the **current** best answer except remove --save-dev. As you want bootstrap to deployed with your app.

Answer (score 2):

**For Adding Bootstrap and Jquery both**

```
npm install bootstrap@3 jquery --save
```

after running this command, please go ahead and check your node_modules folder you should be able to see bootstrap and jquery added into it.

Comment: Cool adding Jquery as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you have just started with angular and bootstrap then simple answer would be below steps:
1. Add node package of bootstrap as dev dependency

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

2. import bootstrap stylessheet in angular.json file.

   `"styles": [
                 "projects/my-app/src/styles.scss",
                 "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
               ],`
3. and you are ready to use bootstrap for styling, grid etc.

   `<div class="container">My first bootstrap div</div>`

The best part of this which I found was that we are directing using bootstrap without any third-party module dependency. We can upgrade bootstrap anytime by just updating the command `npm install --save bootstrap@4.4` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Updated Aug-2020: Angular 10

> "If you have an Angular ≥ 9 CLI project, you could simply use our schematics to add ng-bootstrap library to it." Just run the following command inside your project folder. All the configurations will be automatically added.

`ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

`ng s`

Sample Snippets:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({selector: 'ngbd-alert-basic', templateUrl: './alert-basic.html'})
export class NgbdAlertBasic {
}
```

```html
<p>
  <ngb-alert [dismissible]="false">
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
  </ngb-alert>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

First install **Bootstrap**

```
npm i bootstrap
```

import into angular.json style

```
"styles": [
   "styles.scss",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

`angular-cli` now has a dedicated [wiki page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap) where you can find everything you need. TLDR, install `bootstrap` via `npm` and add the styles link to "styles" section in your `.angular-cli.json` file

Answer (score 1):

Working example in case of using angular-cli and css :

1.install bootstrap

npm install bootstrap tether jquery --save

2.add to .angular-cli.json

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

install boostrap using npm

```
npm install boostrap@next --save
```

then check your node_modules folder for boostrap.css file(within dist) normally the path is

```
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
```

add this path | import boostrap within style.css or style.scss

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";  //bootstrap
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css // angular material theme
```

that's it.

Comment: What about putting it in styles array of `angular-cli.json`? Not neccessary?

Comment: No Its not necessary. since we include our style.css file in that array. we can import other css files in our style.css or style.scss    

    "@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
    "@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

Comment: Ah ok.. but I think including in `angular-cli.json` is probably better

Comment: @CodyBugstein I'm not sure if it's necessarily "better" to add it to .angular-cli.json.  Here are some reasons why you may want to add imports in your styles.scss file:  1) You can easily apply a bootstrap theme like the Bootswatch example here: https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/ 2) Editing .json files is more cumbersome than editing .scss files because .json files don't allow comments, and 3) new developers may look at styles.scss as a starting point for all CSS rather than .angular-cli.json.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't see this one here:

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

I just added this line in style.scss
In my case i also wanted to override bootstrap variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to [add Bootstrap 4 in your Angular project](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-bootstrap/):

- Including the Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript files in the  section of the index.html file of your Angular project with a  and  tags,
- Importing the Bootstrap CSS file in the global styles.css file of your Angular project with an @import keyword.
- Adding the Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript files in the styles and scripts arrays of the angular.json file of your project

Answer (score 1):

you can install bootstrap in angular using `npm install bootstrap` command.

and next setup bootstrap path in `angular.json` file and `style.css` file.

you can read a full blog about how to install & setup bootstrap in angular,  [click here to read full blog about this](https://whiteweb7.blogspot.com/2020/05/how-to-use-bootstrap-in-angular-first.html)

Answer (score 0):

A working example in case of using angular-cli:

```
npm i bootstrap-schematics
ng generate bootstrap-shell -c bootstrap-schematics -v 4
npm install
```

Works for css and scss. Bootstrap v3 and v4 are available.

More information about bootstrap-schematics please find [here](https://github.com/slupekdev/bootstrap-schematics/blob/master/src/shell/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

Install bootstrap using `npm i --save bootstrap@version`.Now,go to nodemodules folder and from bootstrap folder copy the path of 'bootstrap.min.css.js' and paste the full path(like `nodemodules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.js`) in `angular.json` under script tag file and re-run the server and to check whether the installation is successful run the program in any browser you like and press F12 you'll find a part of the window gets opened,now go to elements tab open head tag and if you see bootstrap in style tag,then your installation is successful.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which JS framework you are using, importing bootstrap to your project is easy by following 2 steps below:

Install bootstrap using `npm i -S bootstrap` or `yarn add bootstrap`.

In `styles.css` or `styles.scss`, import bootstrap as `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these three lines in Head tag in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: index.html takes care of every thing.
and it is like we add bootstrap to normal html page

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your styles.css file

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Good News! Basically, Bootstrap 5 can be implemented easily now, and you don't even need jQuery.

From your terminal, just run

```
npm install bootstrap@next --save
```

So, Angular uses webpack, therefore, in your app.module.ts, just add:

```
import "bootstrap";
```

Or if you want to import them separately, do it like:

```
import { ModuleToBeImported } from 'bootstrap';
```

Then to your styles.scss, add:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Basically that's it, BUT beware that some components require popper.js.
[Components requiring bootstrap's js](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#components)
There you'll see the components dependent on popper.js too, which at the time of writing this are Dropdowns for displaying and positioning, and Tooltips and popovers for displaying and positioning.

Therefore, to install popper.js, just run:

```
npm install @popperjs/core
```

[Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/webpack/)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Step

1. Using Angular-CLI execute `npm install --save bootstrap`
2. Add  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" in angular.json file`"styles": [ "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.css" ],`