# how to add ng2sweetalert and ng2fontawesome to angular2 cli

Tags: angular, font-awesome, sweetalert

[ng2-sweetalert2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-sweetalert2)

[ng2-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-fontawesome)

i want to add this to my angular2 cli project
what i must add in my angular-cli-build.js

```
vendorNpmFiles: [
   ..................
   'ng2-bootstrap/**/*.js', <--- for example
    ....................
  ]
```

my system-config.ts

```
const map:any ={
     ..................
   'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap',
    ....................

}
const packages: any = {
  'ng2-bootstrap': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js'

  }

};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The repo wiki has the answer to this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

Comment: is that the same? cause in that link just how to import js, not css

Comment: @Rommy Your css should be external to the CLI. You can write some gulp task to concatenate and output the file into your dist folder. See more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37981280/1565402)