# Angular-cli cannot reference bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular-cli, twitter-bootstrap-4

Using [Angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), I'm trying to reference bootstrap.css

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <base href="/">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        ...
    </head>
    <body> Angular-cli auto generated code </body>
    <html>
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.2"  
 }
```

Now i understand that `ng build` creates a `dist` project and in `vendor` folder
Are all the includes that are needed, And I've managed to add to the `vendor` folder the bootstrap file by:

**system-config.js**

```
// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
 map: {
    ...
    'bootstrap': 'vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
 },
 packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
 });
```

and **angular-cli-build.js**

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
       ...
       'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
    ]
});
```

};

But still The server couldn't find `bootstrap.css`

*Notes*

1. I'm not looking for a `CDN` solution, I want to understand how to import things from `node_modules`
2. Not looking for `ng2 angular directives so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project) is not really a valid solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

In the dist folder there should be no node_modules folder, instead there is a vendor folder which you should use.

EDIT: see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

Comment: Yes, I've specified that i've managed to do it. but i'm not sure it's the way to go + i need to modify both angular-cli-build.js and system-config.ts which i think is big hassle + the worst => no intellisense autocomplete which is absolutely unacceptable (-;

Comment: This is the way to go for now. For every external dependency you have to do this. They are going to simplify this process however, don't know when.
Edited my post with more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont get any npm for your third-party libraries. Make an assets folder under your src folder. Then you can add separate folders for `js`,`css` and `images`. Put your third-party `css` inside the `css`folder. Then you have to reference `css` file in your `index.html` like this way:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/your_css.css" />
```

Now, when you do `ng serve` or `ng serve` it will automatically update the public folder with your `assets/css`. Hope you understand the whole scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn´t reference to css directly to the node_modules because this dir is outside your angular ap:

You have three possibilities to link the bootstrap css, the first one is **copy bootstrap** in your **assets** dir, and link with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

The second on is to get the css from the ** Bootstrap public CDN**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And the third one is to use a **library like [ng2-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)** (I am using it): the steps to install are easy, and you can read it from [this link](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md)  or I will copy it:

```
npm install ng2-bootstrap --save
```

in your **src/app/app.module.ts** and add

```
import { AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
...

@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [AlertModule.forRoot(), ... ],
    ... 
})
```

open angular-cli.json and insert a new entry into the styles array

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
```

open src/app/app.component.html and add

```
<alert type="success">hello</alert>
```

this lib worked ok for me