# How to add css library to project generated with angular-cli@webpack

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack, angular-cli

After creating new project and upgrading it to webpack version I wanted to add bootstrap's CSS.

I tried method descibed in docs [1] but it doesn't seem to work.

I cannot use the cdn version because my users may have to work without acces to external networks.

[1] https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation

```
"apps": [
    {
      "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ],
...
```

.

```
$ ng --version
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2
node: 5.4.1
os: linux x64
```

or maybe I just don't understand what should happen?
after `ng build` in `dist` dir there is no CSS file and there is nothing added to `index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3` or higher, you can use the `apps[0].styles` property of `angular-cli.json` to list external stylesheets for import. With this you don't have to add anything to `index.html`.

To upgrade from `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2` to `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3`, run:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3
```

Note: you may need to upgrade to Node.js 6 if you get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...` errors on running `ng version`. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1883 for details.

If you generate a new project and install Bootstrap, your `angular-cli.json` should look something like this:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3",
    "name": "demo"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "lazyRoutePrefix": "+"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to add ../ front of the node_modules, because node_modules folder is one step up in the directory tree.
Like this:
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

Comment: I should include that in question. I have tried both versions (with and without `../`) with same effects (well... no efect).

Comment: Maybe you could use [ng2-bootsrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)

Comment: ng2-bootstrap adds only js and no CSS so installing it doesn't help. And method of providing CSS provided in quistion doesn't work with webpack

Answer (score 0):

All your css files from `apps[0].styles` property of `angular-cli.json` during `ng build` are compiled into styles.bundle.js and this file is included in `index.html`. If you check this file you can found there all styles. So it works as intended.