# bootstrap 4 in Angular 2 dropdown not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have followed the following to install bootstrap 4 into my Angular 2 project: [Accepted Answer, following the first 1,2,3 and 4 steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)

However when I add the following `HTML` to my header component:

```
<nav class="navbar-dark bg-inverse">
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="nav-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SomeEmail@hotmail.com</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="nav-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sign Out</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see its a dropdown basically, when I click on the dropdown the page refreshes, instead it doesn't display the 'sign out' option.

This is my `angular-cli.json` styles section:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

And inside my Angular 2 module:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

I then import NgbModule into the imports section.

I've clearly missed something, can someone shed any light into what it maybe exactly?

Comment: Here's how to add ng-bootstrap to your module: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started. And here's how ng-bootstrap dropdowns work: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown. You can't just use the documentation of bootstrap and hope the exact same markup will work with ng-bootstrap: the point of ng-bootstrap is to allow using bootstrap components like dropdown in an angular way.

Comment: Thanks for the links! helped me out massively! got it working using ngbDropdown

Comment: Notice that bootstrap 4 is alpha and is not good idea to use it for projects. Because it will have lots of changes and is not stable. Just use it for learning for future.

Comment: @HassanFalahi I'm only using it for learning.

Answer (score 16):

1. Please install ng-bootstrap from this link [Getting Started](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)  with the following command:

   ```
   npm `install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
   ```
2. Import it on `app.module.ts` like

   ```
   import `{NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`
   ```
3. Import on

   ```
   imports:[
      NgbModule.forRoot(),
   ]
   ```
4. Add `ngbDropdown` on dropdown
5. Add `ngbDropdownToggle` on dropdown Toggle DOM
6. Add `ngbDropdownMenu` on dropdown menu DOM

   ```
               <li ngbDropdown  class="nav-item dropdown" >
                   <a ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Manage
                   </a>
                   <div ngbDropdownMenu  class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save Data</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fetch Data</a>

                   </div>
                 </li>
             </ul>
   ```

Answer (score 15):

Variation on @VictorLuchian for newest **BS4 beta**, it seems 'show' class need to be added on the dropdown-menu as well.
This version include a click outside close instead of mouseout

```
import { Directive,HostListener,HostBinding, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'; 
@Directive({
  selector: '[customdropdown]'
})
export class CustomDropdownDirective {

private isOpen: boolean =false;
constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { 

}

@HostBinding('class.show') get opened() {
    return this.isOpen;
}
@HostListener('click') open() {
    this.isOpen = true;
    this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.add('show')                
}
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target']) close (targetElement) {
    let inside: boolean = this._el.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if(!inside) {
        this.isOpen = false;
        this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.remove('show')
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Awesome job bud!!

Answer (score 9):

Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you include plugins individually, 
make sure to check for these dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on 
jQuery (this means **jQuery must be included before the plugin files**).

In `.angular-cli.json` add the following lines to the scripts section:

```
# version 4.x
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
  ]
```

[Checkout definition here](https://github.com/GoNode5/angular-cli/blob/9c264178d2c9a8dc3373648ccd84d5944ca589fc/docs/documentation/stories/include-bootstrap.md#adding-full-bootstrap-component-js-support)

Comment: It depends on tether lib as well. Add it to the angular.cli.json

 "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
 **"../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",**
 "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",

Comment: Correct.. but not necessary

Answer (score 9):

Like Andrien's said, you can simplify the code like this.

```
constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

@HostBinding('class.show') isOpen = false;

@HostListener('click') toogleOpen() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.toggle('show')
}
```

Comment: When I click on the drop down it redirects to the other page. And drop down is not opening anyway.

Comment: @Artyom maybe you forgot a `href="#"` attribute in it

Comment: Definitely the cleanest solution. Works great on Angular 8 + Bootstrap 4.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add a dropdown directive in order for this to work.
The directive looks like this:

```
import { Directive,HostListener,HostBinding } from '@angular/core'; 
@Directive({
selector: '[appcustomdropdown]'
})
export class CustomdropdownDirective {

constructor() { }

@HostBinding('class.open') get opened()
{
return this.isOpen;
}
@HostListener('click') open()
{
this.isOpen=true;
}
@HostListener('mouseleave') close()
{
this.isOpen=false;
}
private isOpen=false;
}
```

Then, you will add the attribute like so:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" appcustomdropdown >
```

Comment: With Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha6 Dropdown with buttons, I changed  'class.open' to  'class.show' to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

[Example Code StackBliz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-boostrap-dropdown-directive)

Firstly Bootstrap 3 & 4 Drop down active state  classes are different

1. In Boostrap 3 : In dropdown open state;  .dropdown-toggle parent element is added '**open**' CSS class
2. Where as in Boostrap 4 make use of  "**show**" CSS class
   In drop down open state. Here .dropdown-toggle element's parent element and next sibling element with CSS class  .dropdown-menu are added "**show**" css Class

Hence to make boostrap 4 dropdown working with angular 4 we will create new angular directive class and add it to boostrap dropdown in angular template

**Step 1 - Crate new angular directive in  ng-boostrap-dropdown.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNgBoostrapDropdown]'
})
export class NgBoostrapDropdownDirective {

  private isShow: boolean = false;
  private dropdownParentEl = this.elementRef.nativeElement.closest('.dropdown');
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }


  @HostListener('click') open() {
    this.isShow = !this.isShow;
    if (this.isShow) {
      this.dropdownParentEl.classList.add('show');
      this.dropdownParentEl.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").classList.add('show');
    } else {
      this.dropdownParentEl.classList.remove('show');
      this.dropdownParentEl.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").classList.remove('show');
    }
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) && this.isShow) {
      this.dropdownParentEl.classList.add('show');
      this.dropdownParentEl.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").classList.add('show');
    } else {
      this.dropdownParentEl.classList.remove('show');
      this.dropdownParentEl.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").classList.remove('show');
      this.isShow = false;
    }
  }

}
```

**Step 2 : Import this Directive in app.module.ts**

```
import { NgBoostrapDropdownDirective } from './directives/ng-boostrap-dropdown.directive';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [ AppComponent, NgBoostrapDropdownDirective ],

})
```

**Step 3 : Apply directive in Template using appNgBoostrapDropdown**

```
NAVIGATION : 
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" >
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" appNgBoostrapDropdown  href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

BUTTON DROPDOWN : 

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" appNgBoostrapDropdown type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example Code StackBliz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-boostrap-dropdown-directive)

Comment: When I click on the drop down it redirects to the other page. And drop down is not opening anyway in this solution as well. I assume it's because a tag that redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Rahul Talar's first version(Step 1 - Crate new angular directive in ng-boostrap-dropdown.directive.ts), i've made some similar using Rendere2

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class AppDropdownDirective implements OnInit {
  private isShow = false;
  private classShow = 'show';
  private parentNode: HTMLElement;
  private siblingNode: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parentNode = this.renderer.parentNode(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
    this.siblingNode = this.renderer.nextSibling(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
  }

  @HostListener('click') open() {
    this.isShow = !this.isShow;
    if (this.isShow) {
      this.addClass();
    } else {
      this.removeClass();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) clickout(event) {
    if (this.elementRef.nativeElement !== event.target && this.isShow) {
      this.removeClass();
      this.isShow = false;
    }
  }

  private addClass() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.parentNode, this.classShow);
    this.renderer.addClass(this.siblingNode, this.classShow);
  }

  private removeClass() {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.parentNode, this.classShow);
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.siblingNode, this.classShow);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Angular 8 and Bootstrap 4.2 this is the working solution I'm using :

1- First I've created a custom directive. What it does is listen to the on click event of the dropdown container and toggle the .show class of the .dropdown-menu element (Bootstrap 4 standard behavior). Also, it will close the dropdown menu if there's a click everywhere else on the document.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, HostListener, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective implements OnInit {
  dropDownMenu: HTMLElement;
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) toggleOpen(event: Event) {
    if ( this.dropDownButton.nativeElement.contains(event.target) ) {
      this.dropDownMenu.classList.toggle('show');
    } else {
      this.dropDownMenu.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }

  constructor(private dropDownButton: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dropDownMenu = this.dropDownButton.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
  }
}
```

2- Once your directive is created and registered. Be sure to apply the directive to the dropdown element, like on this example:

```
<div class="btn-group" appDropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Dropdown menu<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS needs to be in the `<head></head>` tag.
I quote from bootstrap

> Copy-paste the stylesheet `<link>` into your `<head>` before all other
>   stylesheets to load our CSS.

I continue quoting

> Add our JavaScript plugins, jQuery, and Tether near the end of your
>   pages, right before the closing  tag. Be sure to place jQuery
>   and Tether first, as our code depends on them.

Make sure that you have in this way 
here is the link to bootstrap documentation where i get this quotes
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/

and check this answer in the post that you share the link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39809447/3284537

Answer (score 0):

Somebody has created a new version of the template library specifically design for Angular 2+. According to the website, it was developed by ng-team, although the link it gives gets a 404 response. It does work, though, and I have used it in multiple places throughout my current project. You'll just have to pull in the library with npm. All of the instructions are on this website:

http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

That page shows you all of the install and usage instructions you need to get started. I hope this helps!

Comment: The page you link to is not a project by bootstrap

Comment: It works very will with Angular 4, though, and is a great resource. It uses all of the bootstrap objects and provides working templates for all of them. According to the website, it was made by ng-team, which I missed before.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of it, using it myself on a project in fact.  My comment was merely to correct the fact that it is not supplied by bootstrap :) Thank you for correcting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

i have used a different approach for getting drop down on collpased navbar.

**STEP 1**
Add click event on navbar toggle button

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="OnClik()" data-target="#myNavbar"
```

**Html**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="OnClik()" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " [ngClass]="{'show': buttontoggled}" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Step2:**
implement the function inside 
Navbar component.ts   (Above navbar html  template is used inside navbar component)

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
    export class HeaderComponent  {
      buttontoggled:boolean:false;

    OnClik(){
      this.buttontoggled=!this.buttontoggled;
    }
```

**Step 3**
based on the navbar toggle button click   add class *show*(bootstrap 4)  or `open`  for previous bootstrap versions.
we can use ngClass Directive for this

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " [ngClass]="{'show': buttontoggled}" id="myNavbar">
```

**Work flow**

Navbar toggle button will be visible when navbar geting collapsed for smaller resolutions

by handling the button click event we can set one flag to  check if the button clicked or not

Based on this flag we will 
 we will bind the css class show to navabr div   using ngClass directive

Comment: When I click on body dropdown is not being hide.

Answer (score 0):

I am using theme which is not build for Angular and it contain classic bootstrap, I had same issue and fixed by modifying bootstrap.js file.

Issue is that bootstrap listen events with $(document).on and problem is in "document" part.

In my bootstrap file it is line  18001

```
 /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Data Api implementation
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */


  $(document).on(Event.KEYDOWN_DATA_API, Selector.DATA_TOGGLE, Dropdown._dataApiKeydownHandler).on(Event.KEYDOWN_DATA_API, Selector.MENU, Dropdown._dataApiKeydownHandler).on(Event.CLICK_DATA_API + " " + Event.KEYUP_DATA_API, Dropdown._clearMenus).on(Event.CLICK_DATA_API, Selector.DATA_TOGGLE, function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    Dropdown._jQueryInterface.call($(this), 'toggle');
  }).on(Event.CLICK_DATA_API, Selector.FORM_CHILD, function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Change $(document) to  $("body") and it will work.

```
 $("body").on(Event.KEYDOWN_DATA_API, Selector.DATA_TOGGLE, Dropdown._dataApiKeydownHandler).on(Event.KEYDOWN_DATA_API, Selector.MENU, Dropdown._dataApiKeydownHandler).on(Event.CLICK_DATA_API + " " + Event.KEYUP_DATA_API, Dropdown._clearMenus).on(Event.CLICK_DATA_API, Selector.DATA_TOGGLE, function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        Dropdown._jQueryInterface.call($(this), 'toggle');
      }).on(Event.CLICK_DATA_API, Selector.FORM_CHILD, function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

**navbar.component.html**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown show" appDropdown>
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Categories
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a routerLink="yourLInk1" class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
          <a routerLink="yourLInk2" class="dropdown-item">Item 2</a>
          <a routerLink="yourLInk3" class="dropdown-item">Item 3</a>
          <a routerLink="yourLInk4" class="dropdown-item">Item 4</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a routerLink="yourLInk5" class="dropdown-item">Item 5</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

**dropdown.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[appDropdown]'
    })
    export class DropdownDirective {
      constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

      private dropdownParentEl = this.elementRef.nativeElement.closest('.dropdown');

      @HostListener('mouseenter') toggleOpen(){
        this.dropdownParentEl.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").classList.add('show');
      }
      @HostListener('mouseleave') toggleClose(){
        this.dropdownParentEl.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").classList.remove('show');
      }

      @HostListener('click') toogleOpen() {
          this.dropdownParentEl.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").classList.toggle('show');
      }
    }
```

Comment: There are 10 other answers already here.  Any chance you could explain how your answer is better/different than those?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { 
  }
  @HostBinding('class.show') isOpen = false;
  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen(){
    this.isOpen=!this.isOpen;
    if(this.isOpen){
      this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.add('show'); 
    }
    else{
      this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.remove('show');
    }
  }

}
```