# Angular 4: How to include Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm a backend developer and I'm just playing around with Angular4. So I did this installation tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdlbFEsAGXo.

Given this, how can I add bootstrap to the app so I could use the class "container-fluid" or "col-md-6" and stuff like that?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project

Comment: See: http://coderjony.com/blogs/how-to-add-bootstrap-in-an-angular-application/

Answer (score 200):

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

afterwards, inside angular-cli.json (inside the project's root folder), find `styles` and add the bootstrap css file like this:

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "styles.css"
],
```

**UPDATE:**
in angular 6+ `angular-cli.json` **was changed** to `angular.json`.

Comment: That's also working but I guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project is the one which I'd need to go with. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: How to add bootstarp js and jquery js?

Comment: To put the js you must go to angular-cli.json and put "scripts": ["../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"], and you have the js

Comment: Could you explain me why `../node_modules [...]`? For me it should be just `/node_modules [...]`.

Comment: @vnbrs this is a path relative to index.html. If you create app using angular cli your index.html sits in `./src` relative to app's root. If your setup is different you can adjust the path accrodingly.

Comment: @Sevron sure, this installs whatever is the latest here https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap, but you can install any css package in the same fashion - just specify the correct module name.

Comment: I had to change this to `../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` (i.e. without the `.min`).

Comment: you need to put bootstrap, poperjs, jquery to scripts for full usability https://stackoverflow.com/a/54706908/3209523

Answer (score 110):

Watch Video or Follow the step

[Install bootstrap 4 in angular 2 / angular 4 / angular 5 / angular 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j142hRUnB_Y)

There is three way to include bootstrap in your project 

1) Add CDN Link in index.html file 
2) Install bootstrap using npm and set path in **angular.json** **Recommended**
3) Install bootstrap using npm and set path in index.html file

I recommended you following 2 methods that are installed bootstrap using npm because its installed in your project directory and you can easily access it

**Method 1**
Add Bootstrap, Jquery and popper.js CDN path to you angular project index.html file

Bootstrap.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
Bootstrap.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
Jquery.js
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
Popper.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js

**Method 2**
1) Install bootstrap using npm

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

after the installation of Bootstrap 4, we Need two More javascript Package that is Jquery and Popper.js without these two package bootstrap is not complete because Bootstrap 4 is using Jquery and popper.js package so we have to install as well

2) Install JQUERY

```
npm install jquery --save
```

3) Install Popper.js

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

Now Bootstrap is Install on you Project Directory inside **node_modules** Folder

open **angular.json** this file are available on you angular directory  open that file and add the path of bootstrap, jquery, and popper.js files inside **styles[]** and **scripts[]** path see the below example

```
"styles": [   
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [  
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

**Note:** Don't change a sequence of js file it should be like this

**Method 3**
Install bootstrap using npm follow **Method 2** in method 3 we just set path inside index.html file instead of **angular.json** file

bootstrap.css

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css">
```

Jquery.js

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"><br>
```

Bootstrap.js

```
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"><br>
```

Popper.js

```
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"><br>
```

**Now Bootstrap Working fine Now**

Comment: Angular6: the file .angular-cli.json is called angular.json now. And the path isn't "../node_modules..." anymore, instead it's: "node_modules/..."   Cheers

Comment: I completely forgot to add the scripts in the angular.json and was wondering why the jquery components weren't doing their things. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: What does adding bootstrap to scripts in angular.json do? Do you still have to do include it via "<link rel..." everywhere you want to use it?

Comment: Thank you,it is unbelievable how many sources out there lack this information,especially the bit about popper

Answer (score 46):

> In order to configure/integrate/use Bootstrap in angular, first we need to install
>   Bootstrap package using npm.

### Install package

```
$ npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --save   // for specific version
or
$ npm install bootstrap --save   // for latest version
```

Note: --save command will save the dependency in our angular app inside package.json file.

> Now that we have the package installed with above step, now we can tell Angular CLI
>   that it needs to load these styles by using any of the below options or both:

### option 1) Adding into the file src/styles.css

> we can add the dependencies as shown below:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

### Option 2) Adding into angular-cli.json or angular.json

> We can add the style css files into angular-cli.json or angular.json file which is at
>   root folder of our angular app as shown below:

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "styles.css"
]
```

Comment: I wanted to post answer like this, but since its already here i'll just up-vote it. Well done sir. I would just add that in latest version of angular 7 there is no angular-cli.json but instead angular.json.

Comment: In option 2, the css path that worked for me was  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",

Comment: @ИгорРајачић at what level should I add it into json file, can you please give an example link?

Comment: @KuldeepYadav angular-cli.json or angular.json file which is at the root folder of our angular app

Answer (score 12):

### Angular 4 - Bootstrap / @ng-bootstrap setup

First install **bootstrap** into your project using below command:

**`npm install --save bootstrap`**

Then add this line `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` 
 to angular-cli.json file (root folder) in styles

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "styles.css"
],
```

After installing the above dependencies, install **ng-bootstrap** via:

**`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`**

Once installed you need to import main module.

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

After this, you can use All the Bootstrap widgets (ex. carousel, modal, popovers, tooltips, tabs etc.) and several additional goodies ( datepicker, rating, timepicker, typeahead).

Answer (score 10):

In **Angular4** as you deal with **@types** system, you should do following things,

Do,

```
1) npm install --save @types/jquery
2) npm install --save @types/bootstrap
```

**tsconfig.json**

look for **types** array and add **jquery** and **bootstrap** entries,

```
"types": [
      "jquery",
      "bootstrap",  
      "node"
]
```

**Index.html**

in head section add following entries,

```
  <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js "></script>
  <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js "></script>
```

And start using **jquery** and **bootstrap** both.

Comment: After taking build in production the links are throwing error in browser console

Comment: @Vignesh need to see the problem. its hard to say anything.

Comment: It's probably because the files in your node_modules folder are not automatically served to the clients. Instead, add the styles and scripts to the `.angular-cli.json` file, which tells Angular to bundle them with the rest and serve them to the clients.

Answer (score 7):

For below detail steps and working example, you can visit 
https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/

Very details steps with proper explanation.

**Steps:** 
**Installing Bootstrap from NPM**

Next, we need to install Bootstrap. Change the directory to the project we created (cd angular-bootstrap-example) and execute the following command:

For Bootstrap 3:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

For Bootstrap 4 (currently in beta):

```
npm install bootstrap@next --save
```

**OR** 
**Alternative: Local Bootstrap CSS**
As an alternative, you can also download the Bootstrap CSS and add it locally to your project. I donwloaded Bootstrap from the website and created a folder styles (same level as styles.css):

**Note:**
 Don’t place your local CSS files under assets folder. When we do the production build with Angular CLI, the CSS files declared in the .angular-cli.json will be minified and all styles will be bundled into a single styles.css. The assets folder is copied to the dist folder during the build process (the CSS code will be duplicated). Only place your local CSS files under assets in case you are importing them directly in the index.html.

**Importing the CSS**
1.We have two options to import the CSS from Bootstrap that was installed from NPM:

**strong text**1: Configure .angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
]
```

**2: Import directly in src/style.css or src/style.scss:**

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

I personally prefer to import all my styles in src/style.css since it’s been declared in .angular-cli.json already.

**3.1 Alternative: Local Bootstrap CSS**
If you added the Bootstrap CSS file locally, just import it in .angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
  "styles/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
],
```

**or**
src/style.css

```
@import './styles/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

**4: Bootstrap JavaScript Components with ngx-bootstrap (Option 1)**
In case you don’t need to use Bootstrap JavaScript components (that require JQuery), this is all the setup you need. But if you need to use modals, accordion, datepicker, tooltips or any other component, how can we use these components without installing jQuery?

There is an Angular wrapper library for Bootstrap called ngx-bootstrap that we can also install from NPM:

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

**Note**ng2-bootstrap and ngx-bootstrap are the same package. ng2-bootstrap was renamed to ngx-bootstrap after #itsJustAngular.

In case you want to install Bootstrap and ngx-bootstrap at the same time when you create your Angular CLI project:

```
npm install bootstrap ngx-bootstrap --save
```

**4.1: Adding the required Bootstrap modules in app.module.ts**

Go through the ngx-bootstrap and add the modules needed in your app.module.ts. For example, suppose we want to use the Dropdown, Tooltip and Modal components:

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppBootstrapModule {}
```

Because we call the .forRoot() method for each module (due the ngx-bootstrap module providers), the functionalities will be available in all components and modules of your project (global scope).

As an alternative, if you would like to organize the ngx-bootstrap in a different module (just for organization purposes in case you need to import many bs modules and don’t want to clutter your app.module), you can create a module app-bootstrap.module.ts, import the Bootstrap modules (using forRoot()) and also declare them in the exports section (so they become available to other modules as well).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: [BsDropdownModule, TooltipModule, ModalModule]
})
export class AppBootstrapModule {}
```

At last, don’t forget to import your bootstrap module in you app.module.ts.

import { AppBootstrapModule } from './app-bootstrap/app-bootstrap.module';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppBootstrapModule],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

ngx-bootstrap works with Bootstrap 3 and 4. And I also made some tests and most of the functionalities also work with Bootstrap 2.x (yes, I still have some legacy code to maintain).

Hope this help someone!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Sass/Scss, then follow this,

Do npm install

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

and add `import` statement to your sass/scss file,

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

Answer (score 5):

Tested In Angular 7.0.0

Step 1  - Install the required dependencies

> npm install bootstrap   (if you want specific version please specify the version no.)
>
> npm install popper.js (if you want specific version please specify the version no.)
>
> npm install jquery

Versions I have tried:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"popper.js": "^1.14.5",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
```

Step 2 : Specify the libraries in below orderin angular.json. In latest angular , the config file name is angular.json not angular-cli.json

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
             "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
```

Answer (score 3):

For **bootstrap** 4.0.0-alph.6

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 jquery tether --save
```

Then after this is done run:

```
npm install
```

Now. Open **.angular-cli.json** file and import bootstrap, jquery, and tether:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ]
```

And now. You ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

As i can see you already got lots of answer but you can try this method to .

Its best practice not to use jquery in angular, I prefer https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md method to install bootstrap without using bootstrap js component which depends on jquery.

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap --save

or

ng add ngx-bootstrap   (Preferred)
```

Keep your code jquery free in angular

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in your project i.e
**npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5 --save**

After installing the above dependency run the following npm command which will install the bootstrap module  **npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap**

Check this out for the reference - https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Add the following import into app.module import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; and add NgbModule to the imports

In your stye.css
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :** 
npm install bootstrap --save

**Step : 2 :** 
Paste below code in angular.json
node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

**Step 3 :**
ng serve

[image]

Comment: After adding bootstrap in project restart your server

Answer (score 1):

Adding bootstrap current version 4 to angular:

1/ First you have to install those:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
npm install bootstrap --save
```

2/ Then add the needed script files to scripts in angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
  "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```

3/Finally add the Bootstrap CSS to the styles array in angular.json:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],`
```

[check this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib)

Answer (score 0):

add into angular-cli.json

```
   "styles": [
         "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [ 
         "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],
```

It will be work, i checked it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bootstrap online and your application has access to the internet you can add

```
@import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Into you'r main style.css file. and its the simplest way.

Reference : [**angular.io**](https://angular.io/guide/forms#create-an-initial-html-form-template)

Note. This solution loads bootstrap from unpkg website and it need to have internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 6 CLI, just do:

ng add @ng-bootstrap/schematics

Answer (score 0):

To install the latest use $ npm i --save bootstrap@next

Answer (score 0):

first install bootstrap in your project using npm
`npm i bootstrap`
after that open ur style.css file in your project and add this line

`@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`

and that's it bootstrap added in your project

Answer (score 0):

|*| **Installing Bootstrap 4 for Angular 2, 4, 5, 6 + :**

|+> Install Bootstrap with npm

```
npm install bootstrap --save

npm install popper.js --save
```

---

|+> Add styles and scripts to angular.json

```
"architect": [{
    ...
    "styles": [
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "src/styles.scss"
    ],
    "scripts": [
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
    ...
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **Angular 6+** add the following lines of code to **angular.json**:

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
          ],
```

Answer (score -1):

you work with cdn for bootstrap and jquery or install bootstarp directly in app
with:

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

also use https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home, but this is not approperiate

https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-bootstrap-with-angular-c83c3cee3f4a