# How to link JavaScript files in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4 and i want use my JavaScript file to work globally and i have declared like this.
index.html `<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

it is working when i have to use them in app-component.html, but problem is that i have another project which as different folders for different pages it is not working there[image: not working here].

if use the same code in app.component.html it is working fine, but i have different pages within that app/layouts/projects/, here in projects it is not working when i declare js link in the index.html, it works fine in app folder but not working inside it's sub-folder

Comment: just add jquery and bootstrap to your package.json(webpack) and do npm i or npm install jquery and bootstrap. Then import it your component and use.

Comment: If you want to add your js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j

Comment: If you want to add bootstrap and Jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557321/angular-4-how-to-include-bootstrap

Comment: thanks a lot, if i wan't to add any external JavaScript  files what should i do like <script src="assets/js/hello.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

No need to add jquery directly in html file. You can do this:

```
1) npm install jquery --save
2) npm install @types/jquery --save
3) in your component : declare var $ :any;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, if i wan't to add any external JavaScript  files what should i do like <script src="assets/js/hello.js"></script>

Comment: you can include extra script in angular-cli.json

Comment: Don't include src in path. So path will be  : "scripts": ["./assets/js/hello.js"]

Comment: yeah i did in the same way, is there any option to declare in index.html and access it.

Comment: You can include in index.html file but you should not do it. What error you are getting while declaring in angular-cli ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164542/discussion-between-hemanth-and-tushar-nikam).

Comment: if use the same code in app.component.html it is working fine, 
but i have different pages within that app/layouts/projects/, 
here in projects it is not working when i declare js link in the index.html, it works fine in app folder but not working inside it's sub-folder