# Bootstrap responsive class not impacting in Angular 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have created one app with Angular 4 and I want to use Bootstrap class for responsiveness. But some how it is not impacting `col-lg-4` `col-md-4` classes.

I am following this link: [Add bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557321/angular-4-how-to-include-bootstrap)

Below is the images for the same:

[image]

In the image there is clearly defined `col-lg-4`, so both the boxes must be in one line but some how it is not doing this.

Comment: "In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows... " This is especially important in Bootstrap 4 because the columns will simply stack/wrap vertically if not placed inside a  `.row`.

Comment: Your question doesn't related to Angular. In bootstrap, you need to wrap <div class="row"></div> around the columns.