# Add Bootstrap 4 to Angular 6 or Angular 7 application

Tags: angular, npm, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, angular7

I am working on Angular application using bootstrap 4.

I need help related to scss adding in my angular application.

My question is:

- **Is the way of adding bootstrap 4 scss same in Angular 6 and Angular 7 or not?**

**i.e.**

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

**And, open angular.json file and add bootstrap file path to the styles section. Like:**

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

Is the above way is same for both the version of angular.

Comment: Yes.But note in your script section jquery should come first then bootstrap js.

Comment: yes way is same as before

Comment: I use the same way. But you also need to include theter and jQuery in the scripts.

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: Follow this blog post https://medium.com/@oyewusioyekunle/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-your-angular-project-angular-8-6379fd6a0f46

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to do the following:

**Add Bootstrap to `package.json`** (which is done with npm install bootstrap --save)

**Add Bootstrap to `angular.json`** (jQuery is required too)

```
  "styles": [
     "styles.css".
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
     "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

**Reference Bootstrap in the Angular app** (app.module.ts)

```
import bootstrap from "bootstrap";
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/kmm2q7zvko
Article: https://medium.com/wdstack/angular-7-bootstrap-4-starter-25573dff23f6

Comment: use `"styles.css",` instead `"styles.css".`

Comment: import statement gives error
    node_modules/@types/bootstrap"' has no exported member 'bootstrap'.

Comment: @TheDoctor in your `app.module.ts`, try importing `bootstrap` like this: `import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';`

Answer (score 9):

**OPTION-1**

execute

```
npm install bootstrap@4 jquery --save
```

The JavaScript parts of Bootstrap are dependent on jQuery. So you need the jQuery 
    JavaScript library file too.

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css","node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

**OPTION-2**

`ng-bootstrap` It contains a set of native Angular directives based on Bootstrap’s 
    markup and CSS. As a result, it's not dependent on jQuery or Bootstrap’s JavaScript

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

After Installation import it in your root module and register it in @NgModule 
    imports` array

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
    imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

`ng-bootstrap` requires Bootstrap's 4 css to be added in your project. you need to 
    Install it explicitly via:

```
npm install bootstrap@4  --save
```

In your angular.json add the file paths to the styles 
    array in under build target

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

Answer (score 7):

Bootstrap not working properly in Angular 6 / 7 / 8

I tried most of the solution over web nothing work for me

Only below code work for me

No need to change in angular.json

Directly add below line into style.css file

> @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

because in angular.json already we are providing reference of style.css

Answer (score 1):

Remember, if ng serve is working, stop the server for the changes in the angular.json file to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this path in angular.json file in 
style tag ex:-`enter code 
"styles": [ "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css "}