# Angular doesnt support bootstrap in IE after adding tsconfig-es5.app.json

Tags: angular

I followed the steps at (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455) to make Angular 8 app work in IE and it works fine. After this, when I run npm bootstrap and jquery it doesn't reflect as expected.

I have updated the "styles": [] and "scripts": [] array in angular.json with required path.

The output at http://localhost:4200/ looks plain without bootstrap.

When I run a project without adding tsconfig, Bootstrap works but IE shows a blank screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Bootstrap 4 to Angular 6 or Angular 7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706459/add-bootstrap-4-to-angular-6-or-angular-7-application)

Answer (score 0):

You installed the package, but you also need to edit the angular.json and add the line to include the bootstrap path.  This doesn't occure automatically.

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

Comment: Yes, I have done it. I just pasted the empty array here. But still no change. I am running two Angular projects at localhost:4200/ and localhost:4201/ (without adding tsconfig-es5.app.json). localhost:4201 works fine in Chrome with proper output but not in IE and localhost:4200 works in both browser without bootstrap