# Bootsrap classes are not working in Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded and imported bootstrap in the angular.json file, the same is being imported on the webpage, yet bootstrap classes are not working.

Used: npm install --save bootstrap@3,

Imported to angular using by

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          ]
```

The webpage is also displaying the import of bootstrap in style tag yet still not working.

what else has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Search stackoverflow, there are wonderful answers to your questions such as: [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706459/add-bootstrap-4-to-angular-6-or-angular-7-application)
Judging on the fact you are talking about angular.json I conclude you are using Angular 6 or newer version.

You need to reference it in the build section of angular.json.

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
     ...
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        ...
      }
```

Comment: Hi, yes I am using angular.json and this is the code    "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
              ]

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz link with your setup ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54709408/9377382 in this option 1 worked, installed jquery and bootstrap together.

Comment: It seems you are using a bootstrap component that relies on jquery and the styles are added dynamically. That way yes, you need to reference jquery.

Comment: yes, that seems to be the case, bootstrap button style class works but other jquery relied on compnents like navbar did not work. so, after installing both together it works perfectly.