# jQuery and bootstrap not found in node_modules folder

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, bootstrap-4

everyone. Hope you are having a good day.

I've started an Angular project from scratch, I've installed all the packages I need through `npm`. I've decided to use `bootstrap` and I've found it has to be coupled with `jquery` to work properly. I need to do some collapsible menus.

I used `npm i --save bootstrap` and `npm i --save jquery` to install both libraries. Both show up in the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files but none of them appear in the node_modules folder.

I have both added in the `angular.json` file as follows:

```
[...]
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
 ],
 "scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
 ]
[...]
```

The `bootstrap` library works fine (for some reason) but the `jquery` doesn't, thus things are not collapsible. I tried to change that `jquery` reference route in the file and searched through the `node_modules` folder hoping to find any reference to the plugin but no luck so far. The Chrome console doesn't throw any error whatsoever, so I understand everything should work fine but it doesn't.

What can I do to make `jquery` work properly?

Comment: This answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557321/angular-4-how-to-include-bootstrap

Comment: the last bootstrap (5.0) **not** use jQuery else `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` or `popper.min.js`+ `bootstrap.min.js`, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/ BTW, you can use also bootstrap.css + ng-bootstrap (that has the bootstrap component in an "more angular" way:https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home (now is is betta the solution for bootstrap 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had such a problem too as you told you can't see in the node-model folder so make sure you are on the right path where using  npm i --save jquery :

c:/right-path-of-node-module# npm i --save jquery;

at the end if it was not applicable yet. try to add those files manually.

Comment: I've marked this as an answer to my question just for the sake of the question. I did make it work creating the project through Visual Studio with the Angular template project instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not able to see bootstrap and jQuery in your `node_modules`, there is a problem while installing angular so again give this command below I have mentioned

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then install bootstrap using the terminal, `npm install bootstrap --save`.
To install jQuery use the command: `npm install jquery --save`.