# Dropdown Module is not available in ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular

I am upgrading my project from angular2 to angular4.

While upgrading it's showing that `ng2-bootstrap` is changed to `ngx-bootstrap`, I have added it in my `package.jso`n and updated my modules.

but now when I use

```
 import { DropdownModule,ModalModule, PaginationModule, DatepickerModule, TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

`DropdownModule` is showing error, its missing

previously it was like

```
   import { DropdownModule,ModalModule, PaginationModule, DatepickerModule, TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

then it was working  fine(angular2)

what should i do?

Comment: Whenever you stuck in situation like this visit https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md link and check what changes you need to perform. You will find everything over here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `BsDropdownModule`:

```
import { BsDropdownModule, ModalModule, PaginationModule, DatepickerModule, TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to add bootstrap to an angular-cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)
I was integrating NGX-Bootstrap with angular cli last night and was having some trouble, here is a question very similar using the alert module. The module you are importing is actually called "BSDropdownModule"
The documentation of ngx-bootstrap's dropdowns is here: http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns

Here is a code sample of how to use BSDropdownModule:

```
// RECOMMENDED (doesn't work with system.js)
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
// or
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```