# Bootstrap and Angular 4 - Ng overriding CSS

Tags: angular

I've imported bootstrap CSS into the Angular global style.css, however, the bootstrap styles are being overridden by Angular. For example, my markup renders as this -

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="container">
```

but because of the _ngcontent the following CSS gets applied:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-family: inherit
```

Answer (score 4):

you can change the order of styles that defined in **angular-cli.json** file.

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

you should restart your server since angular-cli does not looks for changes in angular.cli.json

Comment: Same issue as above

Comment: Have you added the css <link>  in your main html?

Comment: no, the css gets injected, but angular overrides it....  I don't think I need to add it into the index.html as I added it to the angular-cli.json. Currently the bootstrap CSS is in node_modules, if I was to add it in the index.css, I would need to move the files into the src directory...

Comment: probably it is about the version of angular and bootstrap. please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)

Comment: Worked for me. Need to restart ng serve.

Comment: You are Genius!:)