# Uncaught TypeError with Bootstrap and Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, electron

I've been trying to add Bootstrap `<link>` and `<script>` tags to my HTML in an Angular project. I get all the CDN from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) but I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: I included the `electron` tag to this question since this is an Angular project running with Electron framework, thinking now it could be part of the problem.

Comment: No errors here. Are you running an add blocker or similar that might be blocking some of this?

Comment: @Zlatko not sure to be honest. But I don't think so. It is Angular project running with the Electron framework.

Comment: I just updated the question including the `electron` tag. At first, I didn't think that could be part of the problem. But maybe it is?

Comment: Could be. In that case, the best thing would be to try non-slim jQuery like someone suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice

```
integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

which to me isn't supposed to be there. this is maybe what's causing the issue.

**ALSO**

Why don't you add bootstrap locally instead? it has a lot of advantages and is how the majority of us do it.

1. in your Powershell or CMD or your IDE (coding program)'s console type either :

   (for Bootstrap 4 (in beta)):

   `npm install bootstrap@next --save`

   **OR**

   (for Bootstrap 3)

   `npm install bootstrap --save`
2. Configure `.angular-cli.json`:

   `"styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "styles.scss"
   ]`
3. configure `src/style.css` or `src/style.scss`:

   `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

or you could use ngx-bootsrap wich is an angular wrapper for bootstrap.

there's ups and downs to that. ngx-bootstrap is missing many components overall and doesn't have the latest and greatest in bootstrap but at least it's tailored for use in angular.

sources :

- https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/
- [How to add bootstrap to an angular-cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)

Comment: Okay. I just did.

Comment: Thanks @tatsu, I ended up adding Bootstrap locally

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with this: 
 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery)

Try to include only the minified version (not the slim.min):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still I'm getting the error :( Now it not only says`at bootstrap.min.js:6` but also includes `at util.js:56` in the error

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap relies on jQuery. In your index HTML, before you include any of the Javascript imports, you'll want to do something like this:

```
<script>
  var $ = jQuery = require("jquery")
</script>
```