# Slides in Bootstrap Carousel are not coming in horizontal form, slides are coming vertically only

Tags: angular, carousel

**Current behavior**
*Slides in Bootstrap Carousel are not coming, slides are coming vertically only. in carousel we expect slides to come horizontally only, I have attached the current behavior screenshots also.*

[image]

**Expected behavior**
*Slides in carousel should come horizontally like this example screenshot below
(example link https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples)*

[image]
**Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions**
*after downloading code from github link https://github.com/gg-gg-v1/v1_ComponentsWithSEO
run npm install
run ng serve --o
will launch in browser*

**Example repository**
*https://github.com/gg-gg-v1/v1_ComponentsWithSEO*

**Environment**
*Angular CLI: 6.2.1
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router*

slider.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarouselConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css'],
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]  // add NgbCarouselConfig to the component providers
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  images = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(() => `https://picsum.photos/900/500?random&t=${Math.random()}`);

  constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
    // customize default values of carousels used by this component tree
    config.interval = 10000;
    config.wrap = false;
    config.keyboard = false;
    config.pauseOnHover = false;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
      }
}
```

slider.component.html

```
  <ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
      <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>10 seconds between slides...</h3>
          <p>This carousel uses customized default values.</p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <img [src]="images[1]" alt="Random second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>No mouse events...</h3>
          <p>This carousel doesn't pause or resume on mouse events</p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <img [src]="images[2]"  alt="Random third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>No keyboard...</h3>
          <p>This carousel uses customized default values.</p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <img [src]="images[3]" alt="Random fourth slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>And no wrap after last slide.</h3>
          <p>This carousel uses customized default values.</p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
```

Comment: Does your console have any errors? is the CSS loaded correctly? you may want to take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project

Answer (score 0):

You've not imported bootstrap.css. Import that in angular.json styles array or in `index.html` directly give cdn reference to it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install bootstrap: npm install bootstrap@4
link it in (via index.html) and the same code will work

this was also documented at https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2141

Comment: Thanks for the reply