# Bootstrap modal is not displayed

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I want to display a modal on button click, but the modal doesn't display.

I specified the modal as data-target for a button and I don't get anything and there are no errors on console either.

```
<button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data- 
 target="#someModal">Test</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="someModal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Modal text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
      dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>
 </div>
```

This code is in my component.html page.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and use ng-bootstrap instead of jQuery. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: does your other bootstrap classes working

Comment: @NipunTharuksha yes, they work

Comment: @annie is it working now

Answer (score 1):

You have some empty spaces after `data-` and before `target`. Just put them on the same line and it works. Same goes for `data-dismiss` for the close button.
Also, I'd remove `type="submit"` since it's not required by the official docs: [Modal - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

Here is the working code:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#someModal">Test</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="someModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <p>Modal text</p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does it works after removing those spaces without adding `jquery`

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Boostrap requires jQuery to work. See [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/)

Comment: I also removed that space but it didnt worked till I add `Jquery`

Comment: @NipunTharuksha again, that's because Bootstrap requires jQuery to work. Without jQuery every Bootstrap component that uses jQuery (like modals) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added `JQuery`.So that I have your code by adding `bootstrap JQuery` and its working.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
</head>
  <body>

  <button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#someModal" class="btn btn-danger">Test</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="someModal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Modal text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
      dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

To install bootstrap JQuery check this [How to add JQuery to Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)
Thanks