# Ngx-bootstrap Tooltips not Showing

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular7, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap 4.0.1 in an Angular 7 project with Bootstrap 4.3.1, and i need to add tooltips in some elements of the app.
I followed the [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/4.0.1/#/tooltip) on setting everything up, but i'm unable to get the tooltips showing. Also didn't find anything in Stack Overflow or in other forums that could help solve my issue.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { ModalModule, TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({imports: [TooltipModule.forRoot(),...]})
```

**component.html:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" tooltip="Bazinga!">
      Bazinga
</button>
```

What am i missing here?

**UPDATE: Added package.json information**

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^7.2.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
  "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.0.1",
  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.0.0",
  "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.17.0",
  "angular-highcharts": "^7.2.0",
  "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
  "core-js": "^2.5.4",
  "highcharts": "^7.1.1",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.0.1",
  "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.1.0",
  "ngx-ui-switch": "^8.0.1",
  "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
  "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
  "select2-bootstrap4-theme": "^1.0.0",
  "tslib": "^1.9.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
  "@angular/cli": "~7.3.3",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
  "@types/bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
  "@types/select2": "^4.0.48",
  "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~4.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.4.0",
  "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
  "tslint": "~5.11.0",
  "typescript": "~3.2.2"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you done the [installation instructions](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/4.0.1/#/documentation#installation-instructions) of the bootstrap css in order for styling to work?

Two approaches that works depending how you architect your app.

Either include a CDN, maybe the official one in your index.html with:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or include it in your styling build of the app to your css bundle by in your angular-cli.json answerd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project).

Comment: i installed the component as explained in the documentation: ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component componentName but still doesn't work :(

Comment: thats not what i just explained in the post, did you try either of the two options I wrote?

Comment: after reinstalling the component everything worked! tnx :)