# Angular 8 - How to import bootstrap 4 in assets static files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I am using the syntax for import bootstrap 4 library for static file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

angular.json

```
{
...
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angularapp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/browser-not-supported.html"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.less"
            ]
            ...
          }
}
...
```

browser-not-supported.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Results:

[image]

Dose anyone have same problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add your bootstrap reference link to your styles property in your angular.json file

example:

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.less",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ]
```

Comment: it only work with index.html file, what did I wanted it work for static file in assets section

Comment: an easy workaround would be to copy the link from the bootstrap website however since it is inside your asset folder then perhaps your href is supposed to be "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" instead? Edit: Also after you make these changes make sure you stop your server and close your command line/terminal then run again

Comment: I will consider use the CDN when I don't have any ways import from node_modules

Answer (score 0):

Put your css file inside your assets/css folder then change like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Or include in your angular.json file

```
 "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ]
```

Comment: how I can use it direct in node_modules, I don't want to copy it on css folder. For include it in styles section, that way only work with index.html file(main), not work with static file

Comment: You can only do that by include in your angular.json like I just mention

Answer (score 0):

1) install bootstrap

```
npm i bootstrap
```

2) edit "style" array which is in angular.json or .angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.less",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ]
```

3) import again it into styles.less

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Comment: oh, no no, it only work with index.html(main), not working with static file :D

Comment: @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css']
})                                                                                                                                 can you try this

Comment: It not a component, it is static page `browser-not-supported.html`

Comment: create a new stylesheet file and import it into your html file and check whether it is working or not. if it is working, copy all codes from bootstrap.min.css to new stylesheet and try

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it using npm:

`npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap --save`

For more details visit:

[How to add bootstrap to an angular-cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)

Comment: Thanks, but that ways only work for index.html file

Comment: @dangchithao, Angular is a single page application. All the other content gets rendered in index.html. So you don't need to import it to any other component, you can directly include bootstrap classes and it will be rendered perfectly.

Comment: I need it work with static file which I declare in assets section browser-not-supported.html

Comment: @dangchithao, try by adding it directly to the file as a CDN.

Comment: I said as comment above that I will consider use to CDN, but now I want to use it in node_module :D

Comment: @dangchithao, if you want bootstrap in node_modules, you should install it using npm.For that you can use the command I've given above.