# How to add bootstrap in an Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap

My versions are:

```
1. npm v6.14.12
2. node v10.24.1
3. angular-cli v8.0.2
```

I created a library with these commands:

Step 1: `ng new my-workspace --create-application=false`

Step 2: `cd my-workspace` then `ng generate library my-lib`

Step 3: `cd projects/my-lib/src/lib`

Step 4: `npm install bootstrap --save`

After this I can see **my-workspace/projects/my-lib/package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1"
  }
```

But now I'm stuck. I was to told to add bootstrap either in *style.css* or *angular.json*. But these files will not be there for a library code. Please tell me how to proceed with this. Almost all the articles that I found were for a full fledged angular application.

This means

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably your question not about how to add bootstrap to an angular app but about how to add bootstrap to an angular library.

May be following approaches would resolve your problem.

First add bootstrap in the `peerDependencies` section of `my-workspace/projects/my-lib/package.json` as below:

```
 "peerDependencies": {
     ...
     "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
     ...
 }
```

This will install bootstrap when your angular library is used as a dependency in another angular project.

Then create `.scss` file and put the following line in the file and later on specify it in your corresponding component.

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

After that add bootstrap, like below, in the `devDependencies` section of `package.json` of the angular project containing your library. This will allow you to use bootstrap while you are developing the library.

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

We need add below in our ***angular.json*** file to complete the installation of Bootstrap.

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
 ],


 "scripts": [
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
```

You can also look here for more: [How to add bootstrap to an angular-cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)

Please follow this guide to know more about library creation: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Comment: once you completed the creation process , we can treat lib as normal angular project and same with dependencies import as well. I think you messed things here with this `cd projects/my-lib/src/lib`.  Please recheck your node-modules installation as well.

Answer (score 0):

import direcly in your src/style.css

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```