# How to add font-awesome to ASP.NET Core 6.0 and Angular 14

Tags: asp.net-core, font-awesome, asp.net-core-6.0, angular14

I have created template with ASP.NET Core 6.0 and Angular 14. I want to see how I can add font-awesome and bootstrap into the project.

As I see that bootstrap is should be already in based on list of dependencies from `package.json`. I have checked folder with modules in `ClientApp/node_modules` and I saw most the dependencies except bootstrap. I didn't understand is it embedded using different name or what?

Moving forward I tried to add font-awesome using Package Manager Console. When I typed in

```
 npm install font-awesome --save
```

I got this message:

> up to date, audited 2 packages in 333ms
> found 0 vulnerabilities

What am I missing?

`package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^14.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "run-script-os": "^1.1.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.6"
}
```

Comment: See the following Stack Overflow answer that may help,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67876397/how-to-add-bootstrap-in-an-angular-library