# How to correctly add bootstrap to Angular app

Tags: angular, offline

I created angular app and install bootstrap using "npm install bootsrap" and add the path to angular.json file. but when i create a button and add bootstrap classes the output doesn't show applying bootstrap classes.

[image: here what i get as an output]

Can someone help me to solve this...
thanks

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add bootstrap to an angular-cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)

Comment: Please check my video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePoxNM-Tsjg

Answer (score 5):

**First things** first you want to add bootstrap latest (5) as an npm package like so:

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

In your angular.json add bootstrap stylesheet and javascript:

```
"styles": [
  "src/scss/styles.scss",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
],

"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Now add popperjs and add it to your scripts:

```
npm install @popperjs/core
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Now lets test and see if everything works accordingly
Add a dropdown component to your app.component.html

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button
    class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
    type="button"
    id="dropdownMenuButton1"
    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-expanded="false"
  >
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You should be able to click and view the dropdown menu items

Comment: Thanks this helped! I'd like to add that you can also import the styles, e.g. ```@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";```. Also, instead of adding popper.js separately, you can add it bundled with bootstrap in one go: ``` "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"```.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
npm i bootstrap --save
```

and add the bootstrap in `angular.json`

```
 "styles": [
       "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
       "src/styles.scss"
 ],
 "scripts": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have angular version above 9+ you can use this

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

To get an idea you can refer this document:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Sass**, you need to do the following two steps:

1. Install bootstrap using `npm i bootstrap`
2. In `angular.json` file, add the following line to the `styles` array before any other entry: `"./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"`

Your `styles` array should look like this ("build" -> "options" -> "styles"):

```json
"styles": [
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
```