# Unable to add ng-bootstrap in angular using ng command

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular12

I am new in angular using 12.1.4 version. I am unable to add or install bootstrap dependency in angular. When I run below command in cmd prompt.

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Then it throw an error as shown in below image:

[image: Angular Error]

Comment: Check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project" or "https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `bootstrap` in your `angular 12` app like below. This is only for `css` importing.

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Now you need to import `bootstrap css` directly in `style.css` file like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

However, if you are required to install `bootstrap` with `jquery` and `popper js` then run the following commands like below:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
```

After successfully run the above commands import it in `angular.json` file like this:

```
 "styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
```