# BootStrap 5.0 Styles Not Rendered in Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-cli, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use `BootStrap` in an `Angular` project and was able to render the styles in front-end using the following in the index file of the project:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So far good but was trying to follow this link to render the styles without referencing in the index file [BootStrap with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project). So added the following line in the angular.json file:

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "src/styles.css"
]
```

I believe, this is what the previous link used to do. I am not sure if I had missed something here? What I did is the following and doesn't render the button style:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button> //Though the class name doesn't show while writing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must disable [encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: Just wao! Thanks a lot @Chris.