# angular-cli: Configure sass-loader to include node_modules in includePath

Tags: angular, angular-cli

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15

node: 6.5.0

os: linux x64

I want to compile the scss file from `bootstrap-material-design` v4-dev branch by putting it in the apps[0].styles[] array of `angular-cli.json`  but I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/bootstrap-material-design/scss/bootstrap-material-design.scss                                               
Module build failed:                                                                                                                                                       
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables"; // from bootstrap node_module                                                                                                          
^                                                                                                                                                                          
      File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/scss/variables                                                                                                     
Parent style sheet: /home/ciesielskico/Documents/Git/reports/node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/scss/_variables.scss                
      in /home/ciesielskico/Documents/Git/reports/node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/scss/_variables.scss (line 45, column 1)       
 @ ./~/bootstrap-material-design/scss/bootstrap-material-design.scss 4:14-148                                                                                              
 @ multi styles
```

angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
                "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-flex.scss",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/scss/bootstrap-material-design.scss",
]
```

On bootstrap-material-design's documentation it says to put node_modules in the includePath of the sass-loader.

Is it possible with the current version of angular-cli?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

## workaround

I've written a node script that is executed as npm post install. Files `webpack-build-production.js` and `webpack-build-development.js` located at `node_modules/angular-cli/models/` should contain **sassLoader** entity and following script will append it automaticly.

```
var fs = require('fs');

const FILES = [
  "node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-production.js",
  "node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-development.js"
];

const ADDITIONAL_LINES = "\
        ,sassLoader: {\n\
            includePaths: [path.resolve(\"node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets\")]\n\
        }\n\
    };\n";


FILES.forEach(function (file) {
  var text = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
  var alreadyEdited = false;
  var content = "";

  text.split(/\r?\n/).forEach(function (line) {
    if (line.indexOf('sassLoader') !== -1) {
      alreadyEdited = true;
    }

    if (line.indexOf(' };') !== -1) {
      content += ADDITIONAL_LINES;
    } else {
      content += line + "\n";
    }
  });

  if (!alreadyEdited) {
    console.log('File is being adjusted by fix script. ', file);
    fs.writeFileSync(file, content, 'utf8');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've got this working but for anyone who is looking for this (ng-cli with Bootstrap and SCSS).

Please have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440312/angular-cli-how-to-add-sass-and-or-bootstrap) and set the preprocessor default style extension to `scss`.

`Node-sass` or any other loader is not required to install. It's working with the small modification of the default extension.

Then you can add the bootstrap style as an import in `styles.scss`. (just change extension of the default styles.css)

**styles.scss**

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

It's also possible to add it to `app.component.ts` as `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css', '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss']` and add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to component annotation to apply bootstrap globally.

I prefer the styles.scss approach because I think this file is intended for global styles.

Comment: I think you could use the following notation to refer to scss in the node_modules: `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`

Comment: but how should we to refer to the generated css in the index.xml in order to load it?