# How add custom globle sass/scss/less file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Trying to add some global scss file to the project but it is not compiling.

all other scss files of the components are compiling correctly.

eg. **app.component.scss** is working

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

the **angular-cli.json** file looks like

```
"apps": [{
        .
        .
        "styles": [
                    "styles.scss"
                  ],
        .
        .
    }],

 "defaults": {
              "styleExt": "scss",
               .
               .
              }
```

the `styles.scss` is not compiling which looks like

```
body{
   background:#f00;
}
```

i have already tried these but still not working

[angular-cli how to add global styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484937/angular-cli-how-to-add-global-styles)

[angular-cli how to add sass and or bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440312/angular-cli-how-to-add-sass-and-or-bootstrap)

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1787

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1492

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1459

**angular-cli version is**

**1.0.0-beta.24**

Comment: I have the same setup that you described and it's working for me, so I think there must be something else.. do you have a project link?

Comment: don't know something went wrong.and don't have any external link working on local PC.

Comment: Sorry, if you have an error message that could be helpful.. also you might try posting your project to [Github](https://github.com/) and sharing it here. Also, you might try starting a completely new project by running `ng new my-project --style=scss` and see if you still have the same issue

Comment: there is also styles.css in src/styles.css after deleting this show this error `ERROR in ./src/styles.css
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'PROJECT_PATH\src\styles.css'`

Comment: For some reason the CLI is looking for the `.css` file instead of the `.scss`. It would probably be helpful to see the entire `angular-cli.json`

Comment: but `styles.css` is not mention in `angular-cli.json`

Comment: I agree that it's pretty strange. Perhaps another file is asking for it? I would try running `ng new my-project --style=scss` and see if you still get the error. This command will setup everything and you should never see a file named `styles.css`

Comment: If you make changes to `angular-cli.json` you must restart `ng serve` as the configuration information is only read at startup, so changes are not picked up until the process is restarted. Just mentioning this as it might be part of this issue.

Comment: Yes man! you are right after restarting it is working now. Thank you so much.